# Connecting my app to local network using smb protocol

Tags: android, smb, jcifs, local-network

I'm trying to connect my Android application to my company local network (`Windows`) using `smb` protocol. The problem is I'm kinda newbie on this matter and something is missing me.
The goal is download the file `AREQA.txt` from the network to the device. However I don't even can verify if the code can trace the file location because the application crashes when I compile it to the device (it loads fine but crashes when I call the `DownLoadF001` procedure). Here's the code:

```
    public void DownLoadF001(View v) {
        jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
        String user;
        String password;
        String filename;
        File localFile;
        SmbFile path = null;
        try {
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null,"@@@@@@", "********");
            path = new SmbFile("smb:\\192.168.1.11/.../AREQA.txt", auth);
            try {
                if(path.exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I already tried to remove the inside `try` from the main one (with all its associated code), and the application stops crashing. However, without it, I can't see if the connection is working.

EDIT: I managed to catch the error (`Exception e1`):

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference`. Any ideas to solve it?

Also, as pointed by @greenapps, I'm calling this procedure from a `.xml` button by `onClick` method.

Comment: If you have a crash then the cause of the crash will be mentioned in the logcat. Please have a look and post the relevant lines.

Comment: You should also tell from where you call that function.

Comment: You are using the `jcifs` library, right?

Comment: @Robert, yes I am.